# is $2\sin^2(n\pi/2)+cos(n\pi)$ convergent? divergent to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, bounded but not convergent, or none of these

Tags: analysis

is $2\sin^2(n\pi/2)+cos(n\pi)$ convergent? divergent to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, bounded but not convergent, or none of these

What I did was graph it and it was a straight horizontal line on $y=1$. Does a straight horizontal line count as bounded? also it goes in both directions so for divergent would it be positive or negative infinity.

Comment: Can you get the first terms of the sequence? Do you see any pattern?

Comment: Yes, there is a limit.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : For every $x\in \mathbb R$ we have $$2\sin^2(x)+\cos(2x)=2\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1$$